# How to solve this maven multi module dependency issue? It's not importing from local m2 after installing

Tags: java, maven, microservices, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I have a project with two modules in that. The parent POM looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>bc</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modules>
        <module>njoy</module>
        <module>api</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

The **njoy** module POM looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>bc</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <version>1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>


    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>njoy</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

</project>
```

The **api** module POM looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>bc</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <version>1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>


    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

</project>
```

I have done **mvn clean install** for the parent POM so that it gets into my local m2 repository. 
Now i want to use this project as a dependency in another project(say experiments) by providing it as dependency.
 These are the folders created in my m2 repo.

[image]

This is my other project where i am using it as a dependency, and the POM for it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>experiments</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>bc</artifactId>
            <version>1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>klk</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

But it cannot find the multi-module project artifact, where there is another dependency which is a single module project(**klk**) and there is no issue.

[image]

Please help. What am i missing here?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The artifact `bc` is just a pom with some modules. It cannot be used as a dependency. You probably thought you can reference "all artifacts" by referencing the parent POM. This is not possible.

The artifacts `njoy` and `api` are jars -- they can be used as a dependency of another project.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So you tell me that i have to add each module as a dependency when i want to refer some multi-module project? Or Is there a way to do it with one single dependency?

Comment: My advice is the same as in other cases: Add all dependencies that you actually need in your project (e.g. because you use them in the source code). If you just need one of the modules, just add that. There is no mechanism to add all modules of a multi-module project at once, but I don't see why you need that.

Comment: Any doubts or questions?

Comment: Oh yes, i was bit busy checking the points out. So lets take a scenario that i have 10 modules in a project(say banking) and i need to interact with them for some reason to withdraw, deposit, calculate interest etc etc. I have to add each one of them as a dependency? or is there any way that exists that bundle them up and gives u a single dependency?

Comment: If you always need all of them, put them into one jar. If all your banking applications need the withdraw.jar, the deposit.jar, the interest.jar and so on, why have different jars in the first place? Just have one banking.jar and you have a single dependency.

Comment: I was actually wondering about maven fat jar could help here.

Comment: No, fat jars are not meant as dependencies, just for stand-alone applications. I meant that you can just merge your modules into one if you always need all of the functionality.